# What is the best approach to compare two files dates in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, file, date

I am building .pkg files.

Each build comes with a log.txt file that is created around 2 seconds later than its corresponding .pkg file.

I now have to write a script to automate release/beta distribution in relevant folders.

Beta builds will be moved to the beta_build folder, Release builds will be moved to the release_build folder.

The version type (beta or release) is indicated in the log file.

Before executing these actions (moving the .pkg file in the right folder, renaming the .pkg file, etc..), I need to find the most recent pkg file (last one that has been built) and make sure to find its corresponding log.txt file (likely the last one that has been created).

```
#Find most recent pkg file

#Most recent pkg files is
most_recent_pkg_files = Dir.glob("/*pkg").max_by {|f| File.mtime(f)}
puts each_most_recent_pkg_files

#Most recent pkg file time is
most_recent_pkg_file_time = File.new(most_recent_pkg_files).mtime
puts most_recent_pkg_file_time

#Find most recent log file:

#Most recent log file is:
most_recent_log_file = Dir.glob("/logs/*").max_by {|f| File.mtime(f)}
puts most_recent_log_file

#Most recent log file time is:
most_recent_log_file_time = File.new(most_recent_log_file).mtime
puts most_recent_log_file_time
```

---

Output:

Most recent pkg files is/are:

→ build.pkg

→ 2021-03-05 07:12:54 +0100

Most recent log file is:

→ log.txt

→ 2021-03-05 07:12:56 +0100

I could work with this already and reasonably confirm that the most recent log.txt file must correspond to the most recent build.pkg file.

But for some reasons, I must add a second level of verification.

This is why I would like to compare these 2 dates/strings to make sure that their values are "close enough". Let's say 2 minutes close.

---

Here is the problem in more details:

**2021-03-05 07:12:54 +0100** (pkg) is not equal to **2021-03-05 07:12:56 +0100** (log).

Let's take a more delicate situation; We are now building around midnight:

**2021-03-05 23:59:59 +0100** (pkg) is very not equal to **2021-03-06 00:00:01 +0100** (log).

---

So here is the obstacle:

I need a way to compare these two dates, allow a certain time-based difference (let's say 2 minutes) and I cannot use extra convenient Ruby libraries (it has to be executable in default macOS systems, recent OS versions).

The comparison would return true if the two dates are close enough (2 minutes different max).

The comparison would return false if files dates are different by more than 2 minutes.

Any thoughts ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mtime` gives you a Time, not a string.
You can "subtract" Time objects, resulting in seconds. If a and b are both files, you can do something like

```
(b.mtime - a.mtime).between?(0, 120)
```

which would return false if b is more then 2 minutes older than a.

Comment: pkgtime_logtime_match = (File.mtime(most_recent_log_file) - File.mtime(most_recent_pkg_files)).between?(0, 120)
puts pkgtime_logtime_match

=> true 

Works perfectly. Thanks !

Comment: Typo alert: 'fives' -> 'gives'.